# Is my mango seed growing healthy. Should i plant

Tags: mango

The tip/shoot of the seed was white and now it is turning brown. Should I plant in the pot or do I leave it inside the wet paper towel.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it has sprouted on the top, right? I´d leave it in paper towel until it has 5cm or so and then plant it. You can check [here](https://empressofdirt.net/grow-mango-seed/)